# Replacing file text with sed

Tags: bash, sed, terminal

I'm doing a bash script and i have a txt file and i need edit some text inside it

I need to replace this

```
<h3> >> 1.10 Ping Desde XXXXXXXXXX01-PRD a 10.xxx.xx.xx ==> [ OK ] </h3>
```

to this

```
<h3> >> 1.10 Ping Desde XXXXXXXXXX01-PRD a 10.xxx.xx.xx ==> <span style="color: green">[ OK ] </span></h3>
```

I've trying with sed but with no success.

I've done this

```
sed -i 's/==> [ OK ]/==> <span style="color:green">[ OK ]</span>/g' "temp.txt"
```

with an error response

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 53: unknown option to `s'
```

then i tried a solution implemented for replacing urls, instead of "/" using "%"

```
sed -i 's%==> [ OK ]%==> <span style='color:green'>[ OK ]</span>%g' "temp.txt"
```

with no error message, but no file text change either.

If someone knows how to do it, i'll be grateful

Comment: I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: Maybe i'll check this later, but for what i need the script runs ok with sed,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to escape the opening square brackets for your code to function

```
$ sed 's%==> \[ OK ]%==> <span style='color:green'>[ OK ]</span>%g' temp.txt
```

Or

```
$ sed -E 's#([^[]*)(\[[^]]*])#\1 <span style="color: green">\2</span>#' temp.txt
<h3> >> 1.10 Ping Desde XXXXXXXXXX01-PRD a 10.xxx.xx.xx ==>  <span style="color: green">[ OK ]</span> </h3>
```

Comment: Assuming it's only [ OK ] and not say [ FAIL ] that needs green:
`s%\[ OK ]%<span style="color:green>&</span>` ... just use `&` rather than parens for capture groups.

Comment: The first one is what i needed, actually runs pretty well, thanks, maybe there's a better way to do it, but i did this 
`.sed 's%==> \[ OK ]%==> <span style='color:green'>[ OK ]</span>%g' temp.txt`
`.sed 's%==> \[ ERROR ]%==> <span style='color:red'>[ ERROR ]</span>%g' temp.txt`

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape `[]` in the pattern.

```
$ echo "<h3> >> 1.10 Ping Desde XXXXXXXXXX01-PRD a 10.xxx.xx.xx ==> [ OK ] </h3>" | sed 's/==> \[ OK \]/==> <span style="color:green">[ OK ]<\/span>/g'
<h3> >> 1.10 Ping Desde XXXXXXXXXX01-PRD a 10.xxx.xx.xx ==> <span style="color:green">[ OK ]</span> </h3>
```